# Integral on a quarter circle

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $S=\{(x,y):x≥0,y≥0,x^2+y^2≤1\}$. Then find the integral
$$\int\int_Sxy dx dy$$ How do I do it? I don't have any idea. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: while you can do it using Cartesian coordinates, the symmetry of the problem calls for the use of polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\iint_S xy\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}xy\,dy\,dx =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}x(1-x^2)\,dx=\frac{1}{8}.$$
As an alternative, in polar coordinates we have:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1}\rho^3\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\rho\,d\theta = \frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(2\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{1}{8}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\int \int_s xydxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^\sqrt{1-y^2}xydxdy.$